# Why isHidden isn't working?

Tags: swift, xcode

Does someone know how to fix this problem? I mean, isHidden isn't working, and I have no idea why it's happening

[image: printscreen]

Comment: There's no problem with `isHidden`. The problem is you never connected the `pickerSafra` outlet.

Comment: one more note: please post your code as text and not as image (o make it better searchable)

Comment: I'm using VMware, so I don't know how if it's possible to copy the code and how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly, `pickerSafra` is `nil`

Almost certainly you fogot to connect the outlet in Interface Builder.

If you did connect it, then almost certainly, you have called `showPicker` before the view controller has loaded the nib (which is when it connects the outlets).

Answer (score 0):

**Like rmaddy said problem is not with isHidden.The problem is  problem is your  pickerSafra**.

> You may have not connected properly.Please remove it and add it
>   freshly and properly.Now the issue will not happen.